# Difference between function and closure assignment

Tags: function, swift, closures

Is there any difference in swift between function declaration:

```
func function(a: String) {
    print(a);
}
function("test");
```

and closure assignment:

```
let closure = {
    (a: String) in
    print(a);
}
closure("test");
```

Is there any difference between those?

Comment: One difference is you can't define curried closure but you can define curried function. Another difference is you can't define recursive closure but you can define a recursive function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **Named or anonymous**

   ```
   func function(a: String) {
       print("\(a), name: \(__FUNCTION__)");
   }

   let closure = { (a: String) in
       print("\(a), name: \(__FUNCTION__)");
   }
   ```
2. **Capture List**
   supported in closures only:

   ```
   let obj = FooClass()
   let closure = { [weak obj] in ... }
   ```
3. **Curried function**
   supported in functions only:

   ```
   func curriedFunc(x:Int)(y:Int) { ... }
   let curried = curriedFunc(1)
   curried(y:2)
   ```

   Similar, but not exact the same with using closure:

   ```
   let closure = { (x:Int) in { (y:Int) in ... }}
   ```
4. **Generics**
   supported in functions only:

   ```
   func function<T>(x:T) { ... }
   ```
5. **Referenceability from its own initial declaration**
   supported in **global** functions only:

   ```
   func recursive(var x:Int) -> Int {
       ...
       return condition ?  x : recursive(x)
   }
   ```

   You can do this using closure also:

   ```
   var recursive:((Int) -> Int)!
   recursive = { (var x) in
       ...
       return condition ? x : recursive(x)
   }
   ```

   But this is not recommended because this causes strong reference cycles.
6. **Overload**
   supported in functions only:

   ```
   func function(a: String) { print("String: \(a)") }
   func function(a: Float) { print("Float: \(a)") }
   ```

   n.b. You can reference them as a closure like this:

   ```
   let f:(Float) -> Void = function
   ```

Comment: "But this is not recommended because this causes strong reference cycles." No it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Another difference: **recursivity inside another function**

Nested functions cannot be recursive:

```
func foo() {
    func bar() { bar() } // does not compile
}
```

but closures inside other functions can be recursive:

```
func foo() {
    var bar: (() -> ())!
    bar = { bar() }
}
```